# Does the word 'ask' work in all the cases I'm talking about?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

**Look at this example:**

> *"Did you fix the loose door at home?*
>
> *"No, I didn't have time. But don't worry, I **asked** a servant to fix it."*

The word *ask* has several meanings as I read in dictionaries. In most definitions, it's **request or demand**. Nevertheless, in the above-mentioned case, it's an **order** (to the servant). Is the word 'ask' used correctly here? Or does **told him** work better?

If *asked* is a polite way to *demand/request* something, what if someone made a blunder and you were telling *(asking?)* them to correct it in frustration, how would you say that?

> *Yes sir, it was a blunder and I'm sorry for the loss. I asked/told Tim to correct it earliest.* (**Note: No request needed)**.

This also raises the question in my mind: **Ask Vs. told!** when you demand *(not request)* something.

Comment: In my first language, the use of *ask* vs. *tell* (someone to do something) is virtually identical to the English's usage, as far as I can tell. In my own usage, *ask* literally means *make a request*, and *tell* literally means *say something*. Both terms can be used for giving an order in a polite way, so that the sense of *ordering* will be toned down. From the strongest to weakest among these verbs, I will use *I ordered you ...*, *I told you ...*, and *I asked you ...*.

Comment: Ask always *literally* means request, however politeness often dictates that an order is posed as a request.  You may ask someone to do something to be polite when you both know full well that it really isn't optional.

Comment: It's surprising that any dictionary would define 'ask' as 'demand' - i have never known there to be any similarity in attitude between the words themselves (despite what has been accurately relayed about conventional politeness in conveying 'orders').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usage is slightly atypical - because asking *is* requesting something politely (as others mentioned, not always making it optional, but still politely nevertheless!) and in your case it appears saying "I asked a servant" instead of "I told a servant to..." or "I got a servant to..." puts a small emphasis on the speaker's politeness - and this, in the rules of perfect savoir-vivre might be seen as a bit boastful (about own humility of asking, instead of just requesting.) Never mind that the well-behaved person definitely would *ask* the servant to do this - they wouldn't *talk* about themselves *asking*.

So, yes - as long as the request isn't phrased as a direct (rude/strict) order, no matter if it is a defacto order or not, calling it *asking* is right. But unless you want to emphasize that you were specifically *asking* someone, as opposed to making an order-type request in general, when talking about yourself you'll avoid using "I asked..."

...obviously with exception of when you asked a question, expecting an answer: "I asked him what time it was".

Comment: My parents would routinely reprimand me by saying things like: "I *asked* you to take out the garbage an hour ago! Why is it still here?"